# Powershell string to 2d string array- not char array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, multidimensional-array

Updated: I am trying to take a user input values(string) into a 2d array. For testing purpose, I assigned a string to variable.
Goal: Later I want my program to look at each row for column 1 of my array and do something like install printer software if it says Printer and don't install software if noPrinter. I can do this for 1d array but I want anywhere from 1 to 10 rows. That is why 2d array thought would be complexity.

I want to learn to do this and not ask you to write all my code.
Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
#set user input to a string variable
$UserInputVar = "computer1,noPrinter,Computer2,Printer,Computer3,Printer"

#this is my 2d array; Declare. i want to be able to use anywhere from 1 to 10 rows and always 2 columns
$my2d=[object[]]::(,2)

$my2d.clear #for testing purpose

#assign values of sting to 2 dimensional array
#split the string at each comma(,)
$my2d = $UserInputVar.Split(",")

#show me the values in this array
"`n #my2d[0][0] "
$my2d[0][0]   #expect value 'computer1'
$my2d[0][1]   #expect value 'noPrinter'
$my2d[0][2] 
$my2d[0][3]


"`n #my2d[1][0] "
$my2d[1][0]   #expect value 'computer2'
$my2d[1][1]   #expect value 'Printer'
$my2d[1][2] 
$my2d[1][3]


"`n #my2d[2][0] "
$my2d[2][0]   #expect value 'computer3'
$my2d[2][1]   #expect value 'Printer'
$my2d[2][2] 
$my2d[2][3]


"`n #array with no 2nd index"
$my2d[0]
$my2d[1]
$my2d[2]
```

Comment: that table is NOT a string. [*grin*] please, fix it to be a string ... and wrap it in code markers to keep it as plain text.

Comment: `$my2d = $UserInputVar.Split(",")` will give you a 1d array. Also, what exactly is the question, I'm confused.

Comment: i saw in an example-column 0 had types of fruit and column 1 had prices. I want to take user input as a string and separate it into my2d[0][0] and my2d[0][1] and my2d[1][0]...so on. I don't want initialized values but that is all examples I could find.

Comment: Sorry Lee_Dailey. I put the table at the top just for visual purpose. I changed it and I think I messed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want an object as output, but if so, this is a simple way to do it:

```
$z = 0
$UserInputVar = "This,is,my,strg,to,test".Split(',')

for($z=0; $z -lt $UserInputVar.Count; $z=$z+2)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        1 = $UserInputVar[$z]
        2 = $UserInputVar[$z+1]
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1    2   
-    -   
This is  
my   strg
to   test
```

---

**Edit**

Looking again at the question, this may be what you're looking for:

```
$z = 0
$UserInputVar = "This,is,my,strg,to,test".Split(',')
$result = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
for($z=0; $z -lt $UserInputVar.Count; $z=$z+2)
{
    $result.Add(@($UserInputVar[$z],$UserInputVar[$z+1]))
}
```

**Some Testing**

```
PS /> $result[0]
This
is

PS /> $result[0][0]
This

PS /> $result[0][1]
is

PS /> $result[0][2]

PS /> $result[1][0]
my
```

Comment: I will read up on objects again. The output looks like what I want. I don't know about hashtables but it is also a consideration. This is the first block of code i am figuring out. In the grand scheme, i need association but not object attributes. Simpler. Let me update my question and the string.

Comment: Yes, I like what you have there. I am only 3 weeks into powershell and learning as I write. Buddy suggested 2d array for my project then went on vacation.

Comment: i am running version=4.0.0.0. i get error Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...]] does not 
contain a method named 'new'. I was getting this before with ::new(); I tried to drop it from my original code and no success.

Comment: @call_me_miKe what about `$result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]`?

Comment: i changed new() to @() and all my errors are gone and your code works perfectly. You new version is perfect. Thank you @Santiago Squarzon

Comment: Sorry. This is the whole line  "$result = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@()"

Comment: Makes sense, and happy it worked @call_me_miKe. If the answer was helpful consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), it may help others in the future.

Comment: i spent a week building a 1d array thinking i was on track with this.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use regex matching to return your groups of 2 elements. Then you can split each of those returned pairs into a single array (because of the unary operator `,`). All the returned single arrays are then wrapped automatically into `Object[]` array.

```
$UserInputVar = "computer1,noPrinter,Computer2,Printer,Computer3,Printer"
$my2d = [regex]::Matches($UserInputVar,'[^,]+(,[^,]+|$)') |
    Foreach-Object {,($_.Value -split ',')}
```